# HVAC enegery balance confusion

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

so I'm confused about the conservation of energy for HVAC system in thermodynamics. in my textbook and course, when they do an energy balance for hot steam that is being sprayed into an airstream, this is the equation they got

1= inlet

2= outlet after mixing with steam

a denotes dry air,

s denotes steam,

m is mass,

h is enthalpy

w is ratio of vapor mass to dry air mass

ma1*ha1 + ms*hs=ma2*ha2........................1

i think this is wrong, because for COE( ignoring heat,work,KE and PE) is:

Summation(mihi) = summation(mehe)
which leads to;

ma1*ha1+ma1*w1*hv1 + ms*hs =ma2*ha2+ma2*w2*hv2........................2

equation (1) ignores the vapor enthalpies for energy balance, but it is always used except for the case of an adiabatic saturation proceses, where the vapor enthalpies are included along with the dry air enthalpies.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: Also, please use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, for this particular analysis, the ma's are mass flow rates of moist air and the ha's are the weighted average mass enthalpies, weighted in terms of the mass fractions of air and water vapor.